# NumPy: use 2D index array from argmin in a 3D slice

Tags: python, indexing, numpy

I'm trying to index large 3D arrays using a 2D array of indicies from argmin (or related argmax, etc. functions). Here is my example data:

```
import numpy as np
shape3d = (16, 500, 335)
shapelen = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, shape3d)

# 3D array of [random] source integers
intcube = np.random.uniform(2, 50, shapelen).astype('i').reshape(shape3d)

# 2D array of indices of minimum value along first axis
minax0 = intcube.argmin(axis=0)

# Another 3D array where I'd like to use the indices from minax0
othercube = np.zeros(shape3d)

# A 2D array of [random] values I'd like to assign in othercube
some2d = np.empty(shape3d[1:])
```

At this point, both 3D arrays have the same shape, while the `minax0` array has the shape (500, 335). Now I'd like assign values from the 2D array `some2d` to the 3D array `othercube` using `minax0` for the index position of the first dimension. This is what I'm trying, but doesn't work:

```
othercube[minax0] = some2d    # or
othercube[minax0,:] = some2d
```

throws the error:

> ValueError: dimensions too large in fancy indexing

Note: What I'm currently using, but is not very NumPythonic:

```
for r in range(shape3d[1]):
    for c in range(shape3d[2]):
        othercube[minax0[r, c], r, c] = some2d[r, c]
```

I've been digging around the web to find similar examples that can index `othercube`, but I'm not finding anything elegant. Would this require an [advanced index](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)? Any tips?

Comment: Thank you for having had this problem! My day is better for the answer it induced.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

fancy indexing can be a little non-intuitive.  Luckily the [tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html#fancy-indexing-and-index-tricks) has some good examples.

Basically, you need to define the j and k where each `minidx` applies.  numpy doesn't deduce it from the shape.

in your example:

```
i = minax0
k,j = np.meshgrid(np.arange(335), np.arange(500))
othercube[i,j,k] = some2d
```

Comment: How would this work on 3D index arrays from a 4D array?